# How do I get XCode to break on all console / log messages?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, console, breakpoints

I have a message from it seems Core Foundation printing into the debug console in XCode (OS X app), "CGContextGetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error....".

I don't know where in my app this line is being generated. (big app)

I tried breaking on NSLog(), CFLog() syslog(), printf(), fprintf, and none of those breakpoints stop on that output. All of those breakpoints work if I test them, etc.

Is there a symbol I can break on that will stop every time a message is printed to the console?

Or is there some function that Apple uses that I can break on?

Comment: Have you tried using a symbolic breakpoint? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264193/add-a-symbolic-breakpoint-on-a-selector-in-xcode

Comment: This, by the way, is almost certainly a bug.  It's probably happening when you tap in a text field.